# Getting the Week Number for the Month Crystal Reports Formula

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report `Grouped by (Day,Week,Month)`.
I want to be able to display the "Week Number" for the month. Ex: 1st Week Of July, 2nd week of July, 3rd Week of July, etc. on the "Week" Group Header.

I have tried using a Formula

```
Totext(DatePart("ww", {Command.TransactionDate}),0)
```

But the result is the "Week Number" for the year EX: 33,34,35. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: I would try do this in SQL rather than CR.

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression like this:

```
datevar yourDate := currentdate;
Datepart("ww",yourDate)+1
- Datepart("ww",yourDate - Day(yourDate)+1)
```

of course, replace the variable assignment with your date.

The logic is to get the week number of the date (plus 1) and subtract the week number of the 1st of the current month.